# How to add buttons to notification FCM ionic3

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add three buttons to my push notification with ionic3 using FCM (firebase cloud messages) plugin. The push notifications work without action buttons but when i try to implement them i get an error in the firebase function console. I read a lot of questions about the toppic but none helped me solve this problem..

this is my component code (without trying to implement actionbuttons because those codes did not work, this one does but then doesn't show buttons):

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));

}

onAuthStateChanged(user) {
  console.log('user', user)
  if (user && this.currentUid === user.uid) {
    return;
  }

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) return;

   this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');


   if(user){
    this.saveToken();
    this.currentUid = user.uid;
   }
   this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {

    // alert('message received: ' + data.aps.alert.body);

     if(data.wasTapped) {
     // alert("Received in background");
     } else {
     // alert("Received in foreground");
     };
   });
   this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
     // backend.registerToken(token);
     this.saveToken();
   });
  });
}

saveToken() {
  this.fcm.getToken().then(currentToken => {
    // backend.registerToken(token);
    if (currentToken) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + this.currentUid + '/notificationTokens/' + currentToken).set(true);
     // alert('save token: users/' + this.currentUid + '/notificationTokens/' + currentToken)
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to get messaging token.', err);
    if (err.code === 'messaging/permission-default') {
     console.log('You have not enabled notifications on this browser. To enable notifications reload the page and allow notifications using the permission dialog.');
    } else if (err.code === 'messaging/notifications-blocked') {
     console.log('You have blocked notifications');
    }
  })
}
```

and this is my firebase cloud function:

```
exports.sendChatNotification = functions.database.ref('/app/chat/user/{clientUid}/{trainerUid}/{pushId}').onWrite((event) => {
  const clientUid = event.params.clientUid;
  const trainerUid = event.params.trainerUid;
  const MessageId = event.params.pushId;
  const Message = event.data.val();

  console.log('newly pushed message -> ', Message)
  // If un-follow we exit the function.
  if (!event.data.val()) {
    return console.log('Client ', clientUid, 'un-followed user', trainerUid);
  }
  console.log('We have a new message of trainer with UID:', trainerUid, 'voor client veranderd nu wel?:', clientUid);
  console.log('message en id', Message, MessageId);
  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${(Message.afzender === 'pt') ? clientUid : trainerUid}/notificationTokens`).once('value'); // deelnemer krijgt notificatie van trainer

  console.log(`/users/${clientUid}/notificationTokens`);
  // Get the trainer profile.
  const getTrainerProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(trainerUid);

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getTrainerProfilePromise]).then((results) => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const trainer = results[1];
// Check if there are any device tokens.
if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
  return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
}
    console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');

    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification:{
        title: `Nieuw bericht ${(Message.afzender === 'pt') ? 'van de trainer' : 'van een client'}!`,
        body: `${Message.naam} heeft je een bericht gestuurd.`,
        sound: "default",
        click_action: "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
        icon: "fcm_push_icon",
        // actions: [
        //   {
        //     icon: 'emailGuests',
        //     title: 'EMAIL GUESTS',
        //     callback: 'emailGuests',
        //     foreground: true
        //   },
        //   { icon: 'snooze', title: 'SNOOZE', callback: 'snooze', foreground: false }
        // ],
      // "data":{
      //   "actions": [
      //     { "icon": "emailGuests", "title": "EMAIL GUESTS", "callback": "emailGuests", "foreground": true},
      //     { "icon": "snooze", "title": "SNOOZE", "callback": "snooze", "foreground": false}
      //   ]
      // },
        to:"/topics/topicExample",
        priority:"high"
        // "restricted_package_name":""
      }
  };

    // Listing all tokens.
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  }).then((response) => {
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      const error = result.error;
      if (error) {
        console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
        // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
          tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
        }
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });
});
```

Comment: As far as I know this is not currently possible to do directly with Ionic or Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Here is a link I found that explains how to do it with Flutter. It involves building the required functionality natively alongside the framework code. Possibly something similar can be done alongside Ionic.
https://medium.com/@info_67212/firebase-push-notification-with-action-button-in-flutter-a841da348097